# Program only sends message once

Tags: java, sockets

I have been working on this script for awhile and have been running into this issue that I haven't been able to get working. Basically I start a loop and connect to a socket. Once connected, each string I enter should send to the ip / port I set. However, it works perfect for the first string I send, but after that it won't send anymore strings I type.

```
package keylog;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class keylogger {
public static PrintWriter out = null;
public static BufferedReader in = null;
public static Socket hackee;
private static final ChronoLocalDateTime ChronoLocalDateTime = null;
private static final String BufferedReader = null;
private Scanner keyboard;
public static ChronoLocalDateTime getTime() {
    return ChronoLocalDateTime;
}
public String getLine()
{
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    return keyboard.nextLine();
}
public static void connectToSocket(String ip, int port) throws IOException 
{

        hackee = new Socket(ip, port);

}
public static boolean getStatus()
{
    if(BufferedReader == "quit")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
public void sendData(String s)
{
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(hackee.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hackee.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.println(s);



package keylog;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class keylogging {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    keylogger time = new keylogger();
    System.out.println("Enter the IP address of your target.");
    String ip = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the targetted port");
    int port = keyboard.nextInt();
    time.connectToSocket(ip, port);
    while(keylogger.getStatus())
    {
        String toSend = time.getLine();
        System.out.println();
        time.sendData(toSend);
    }
    System.out.println(keylogger.getTime());

}
}
```

This program only sends the message typed in once. The purpose of this program is for someone to put in the ip and port of the person they want to communicate with.

Comment: Why are you creating a new BufferedReader, and PrintWriter every time? When will `BufferedReader == "quit"` that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @WalterM I was using that as a while loop since the programs not finished. I was just focusing on one problem at a time :). I changed it to a while one loop though.

Comment: what are your input values for IP & Port ?

Comment: @Sabir Khan The values are: 127.0.0.1 (string), and 5056 (int) ... it does work the first time but after that nothing :(

Comment: @Sabir Khan 55056 my bad

Comment: For second time, did you tried printing `toSend` String in `while loop` or within `sendData()` ? I mean, is this an Empty string or not?

Comment: @Sabir Khan I saw that issue, thanks for your help. I have figured it out. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together an example of what you are trying to do. Main point, no need to create a new Stream around the existing one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter IP Address: ");
    final String ip = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Port: ");
    final int port = kb.nextInt();

    //open socket
    final Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);

    //create reader/writer only once
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    //new thread just to read from socket
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                //remote has closed socket. quit
                System.exit(0); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();

    //get keyboard input and send
    while (true) {
        String line = kb.nextLine();
        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            System.exit(0); //user has typed in "exit". quit

        //send line to remote
        out.println(line);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where I'm from, we call this spoonfeeding

Comment: @VinceEmigh Kind of, but this is basically what he's doing already, just in the wrong order.

Comment: It's better to guide the person, rather than give them something they can copy and paste into their IDE. Especially since the asker is new, it could give him the wrong idea on how this site works. He could inform his friends that StackOverflow will hand them code, and this site already has enough of those people. Answers with copy & paste content, without *detailed* explanation of what the problem was, tends to harm the community

Comment: @Vince Emigh Probably, it is convenient however that you have come by to stop me from keeping this idea. He is giving me a more efficient way of coding. I will not simply be copy pasting.

Comment: @Sellex No one is stopping anyone.. His answer is still valid, no one downvoted, and you got the answer you needed. It was simply a suggestion. Better answers tend to attract more upvotes